# How can I use JavaDocs in Eclipse to show conditional return statements?

Tags: javadoc

I have a simple method "ValidateUser" that returns a different string depending on whether or not the user has successfully logged in.

[image: Output specifications]

Right now I've just documented the first possible output.

```
/**
*
*@param user the username of the user
*@param password the password of the user
*@return    True <br>
*           User_First_Name<br>
*           User_Last_Name<br>
*           Num_Records
*
*/
```

What is the best way to use javadocs to show all the possible outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to keep `@return` simple, and put the details in the method documentation.

For example:

```
/**
* Validates the user.
* <p>If successful, returns a string including these lines:</p>
* <blockquote>
* TRUE
* User_First_Name
* User_Last_Name
* Num_Records
* </blockquote>
* <p>Otherwise, returns "FALSE" or "FAILED".</p>
* @param user the username of the user
* @param password the password of the user
* @return  If successful, the multi-line string described above, 
*    beginning with "TRUE". Returns "FALSE" if the user credentials 
*    are invalid. Returns "FAILED" if the operation failed for any 
*    reason (e.g., can't connect to the server, internal server error).
*/
```